# Client server communication java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I have a problem in a client-server application. The client sends a picture to the server and the server responds with a reply message.

Here is my server code:

```
public class Server
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String response="response";
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(3333);
        while (true)
        {
            Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("output.jpg");
            int i;
            while ( (i = dis.read()) > -1) 
                fout.write(i);    

            DataOutputStream outToClient= new    DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            outToClient.writeBytes(response);

            fout.flush();
            fout.close();
            dis.close();
            outToClient.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sentence;
    int i;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ("pathphoto.jpg");   
    Socket sock = new Socket ("hostname",3333);
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Sending....");
    while ((i = fis.read()) > -1)
        os.write(i);

    BufferedReader inFromServer= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    sentence=inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + sentence);
    fis.close();
    os.close();
    sock.close();
}
}
```

The problem is that the client doesn't receive the response from the server and I think along these lines:

```
BufferedReader inFromServer= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
sentence=inFromServer.readLine();
```

Because without them the server sends the response.

Any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: how are you running this? in two separate threds? if yes, are both the threds alive all the time?

Comment: does any one of your applications close down before the other can read/write to a socket? check if you are not closing sockets too fast.

Comment: You have an extra `}` at your client code hope that is just a typo or that it does have something to close.

Answer (score 1):

Its not stuck in *BufferedReader*, it is actually stuck in
*while ((i = fis.read()) > -1)*
Since your client never told server length of stream, or closed stream server will try to read next byte from *inputstream* and will be stuck when client is done sending file and waiting for response from server.

When you remove code to read response back from server, client goes ahead and closes all streams and in that case server reads a -1 and goes ahead.

Comment: i try to put os.close before BufferedRedear but it launch an exception becouse it closes the socket